# how to overcome ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'ODBC'@'localhost' (using password: NO) permanently

Tags: mysql

when am trying to open mysql in windows cmd by typing mysql. the following error is occuring.

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user ODBC@localhost (using password: NO)
```

And then by looking similar queries i somehow got a temporary solution by using 
`C:> mysql -u root -p` and then typing the password, `mysql` is working. But when i close and open, the same problem is recurring.

One more thing is that i have created a user 'admin'. but when am trying to open mysql using the command `C:> mysql --user=admin --password=root`, the following error is occuring:

```
C:\Users\abhay kumar>mysql --user=admin --password=root
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'admin'@'localhost' (using password:NO)
```

Any help will great

Comment: Your post mentions 3 different users. `root`, `admin` and `ODBC`. Are you sure that the `ODBC` and `admin` users exist and they are allowed access from `localhost`? How did you create the users? Please also note that however you're connecting you are NOT using a password (`using password: NO`). Is your *actual* question that you cannot use the command line parameter `--password` on windows?

Answer (score 144):

for some reason, the ODBC user is the default username under windows even if you didn't create that user at setup time. simply typing

```
mysql
```

without specifying a username will attempt to connect with the non-existent ODBC username, and give:

> Error 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'ODBC'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Instead, try specifying a username that you know, for example:

```
mysql -u root -p
```

where `-u root` specified the username `root` and `-p` will make the command prompt for a password.

If you have installed using **Chocolatey** on Windows :-

The default username would be `root` and the password will be `blank`

Comment: I was having this same issue, and from your answer, worked out that there should be no space between the parameter specifier and the argument i.e `-pmyPassword` instead of `-p myPassword`

Comment: use Find in windows and type for ODBC and you will get "set up ODBC data sources (32 bit) or et up ODBC data sources (64 bit)"... click on appropriate one (64 0r 32 bit) and when the windows pop up remove any unsed "USER DSN"... I did it and it resolved the issue for me...

Comment: in my case the following command works `C:\Program Files\mysql\mysql server 8.0\bin> .\mysql.exe -u root -p` 
`Enter password: ******`
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 23
Server version: 8.0.24 MySQL Community Server - GPL

Copyright (c) 2000, 2021, Oracle and/or its affiliates.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql>

Answer (score 11):

You need to create an user "ODBC" for MySql with no password. Do that in PHPMyAdmin. That will solve your problem.

But remember, if it's only your local development environment, no problem. It'll create a serious security hole in your production environment.

[image: User ODBC with no password]

[image: Problem Solved]

Comment: Surely that's a security risk in case someone tries to log in from anywhere as the user ODBC, they won't be challenged?

Comment: bad security practice

Answer (score 2):

I tried this and it worked:

```
C:\cd MySQL installed path\MySQL -uyourusername -pyourpassword
```

Answer (score 2):

```
C:\Users\abhay kumar>mysql --user=admin --password=root..
```

This command is working for root user..you can access mysql tool from any where using command prompt..

```
C:\Users\lelaprasad>mysql --user=root --password=root
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 4
Server version: 5.5.47 MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2015, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.
```

Answer (score 2):

I know it's been three years since this was asked, but I just figured out this problem for myself. I was using `into outfile` and getting the error. When I commented out this part of the query, it worked.

The `FILE` privilege is separate from all the others and must be granted to the user running the script.

```
GRANT FILE ON *.* TO 'asdfsdf'@'localhost';
```

Comment: This continued to baffle me until just now. I was able to run the task if I was signed on with the profile of the user connected to the task but not if the task ran un-signed-on. Finally created an environment variable for SYSTEM user that fixed it. Set APPDATA to C:\Users\nameoftaskrunner\AppData\Roaming. This is so that SYSTEM can find the .mylogin.cnf file that is in %APPDATA%\MySQL that contains the --login-path information for MySQL.

Answer (score 2):

Just create a file *my.ini* file in installation dir and have the below config as part of this file to solve this permanently.

```
[mysql]
user=root
password=root
```

Comment: While this might be OK for a private [lwm]amp stack bound to localhost on your personal development machine, I'd very strongly advise against adding the `password=whatever` line in a production environment.

Answer (score 2):

Try this command:
`mysql -uroot -p`
then it will ask for password
enter `root` as the password.

Answer (score 2):

To overcome the above error, you can simply create the `ODBC` named user:

```sql
CREATE USER ODBC@localhost;
```

And then grant it all the privileges:

```sql
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO ODBC@localhost;
```

This will solve the error. If you want to persist this user, you can, but I would suggest that you delete it once your work has been done:

```sql
DROP USER ODBC@localhost;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using dj-database-url check the schema in your DATABASES

https://github.com/kennethreitz/dj-database-url

MySQL is

```
'default': dj_database_url.config(default='mysql://USER:PASSWORD@localhost:PORT/NAME')
```

It solves the same error even without the PORT

You set the password with:

```
mysql -u user -p
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using following command it work.

```
mysql --user=root --password=root_password
```

Answer (score 1):

Why you can't just use mysqlsh?

```
PS C:\Users\artur\Desktop> mysqlsh --user root
MySQL Shell 8.0.17

Copyright (c) 2016, 2019, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.
Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its affiliates.
Other names may be trademarks of their respective owners.

Type '\help' or '\?' for help; '\quit' to exit.
Creating a session to 'root@localhost'
Fetching schema names for autocompletion... Press ^C to stop.
Your MySQL connection id is 13 (X protocol)
Server version: 8.0.17 MySQL Community Server - GPL
No default schema selected; type \use <schema> to set one.
 MySQL  localhost:33060+ ssl  JS >
```

[image: mysqlsh on windows terminal (pic)]

Comment: A small hint: Answers are better if they are not posted in a form of a question. You are suggesting something, and you should be sure about your suggestion, so others can treat this seriously.

Answer (score 1):

### I have found the answer for this:

enter mysql -u user -p

this will leads to **Enter Password** .

Then enter the password which you have given...

below is the example:
*****C:\Users\admin>**mysql -u root -p**

****Enter password**: **********************

Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 26
Server version: 8.0.31 MySQL Community Server - GPL

This is worked for me

Answer (score 0):

1. open command line (run as admin)
2. go into Mysql server bin folder
3. run command:
   mysqldump -u root -p mydbscheme > mydbscheme_dump.sql
4. give your password here against root.

It will work perfect !!

Answer (score 0):

You can create user with no password in phpmyadmin and it solves the problem!
Lebbar Abdelhadi,

Answer (score 0):

It seems like You haven't set the Mysql server path, Set Environment Variable For MySql Server. Then restart the command prompt and enter **mysql -u root-p** then it asks for a password enter it.
Thank you.
Happy learning!

Answer (score 0):

You can connect to SQL from a python Jupiter notebook  using this syntax:

```
import  mysql.connector as conn
conn.connect(host = 'localhost', user = 'root', passwd = 'xxx')
```

xxx = your password for MySQL
user = your MySQL user name, which might be different from `root`. Check your MySQL `userid`, and change it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Let me what worked for me -

Step 1 - In cmd, give a command

```
set path=%PATH%;set path=%PATH%;C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin
```

> [Note - make sure you are replacing ***'C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL
> Server'*** with your ***'MySQL server path'*** above]

Step 2 - type,

```
mysql -u user -p
```

> This will ask for password and you are good to go but **sometimes
> it does not work...**
>
> Then try this

Alternative of Step 2 -

```
--user=root --password=1234
```

> Must replace your username and password with above

Step 3 - Check out by

```
mysql --version
```

I hope this may help...

Answer (score 0):

I copied shorcut target and it gives me this.Pasting this in in cmd and it works!

"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysql.exe" "--defaults-file=C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\my.ini" "-uroot" "-p"

Answer (score -1):

i entered in Mysql Workbench and i changed the password. It seem the password was expired. it works!

Answer (score -1):

So, all of you missed to say these:

at first install, connect with mysql.exe -u root -p and at password press enter, and you are logged in, create new user or alter root user with new password. create database, etc  !!!

Answer (score -2):

I encountered this problem today. I tried `mysql -u root -p`, but it doesn't work.
I restarted the mysql service by two commands:
`net stop mysql` and `net start mysql`
then tried the command `mysql`. It worked.