# How to start MySQL5.7 server and login windows 7?

Tags: mysql

When I type:

```
mysql
```

in cmd it gives me error:

```
error 1045: 'access denied for user 'ODBC'@'localhost' (using password: no)'
```

After I ran

```
mysqld stop
```

I tried again

```
mysql
```

and still have the same error 1045.
Does it mean that mysql server is running?
How to login to mysql 5.7 on windows 7?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23950722/how-to-overcome-error-1045-28000-access-denied-for-user-odbclocalhost-u

Comment: Thanks but the error is for user `root` too.