# phpmyadmin ERROR 1045 (28000)

Tags: mysql

I can no lnger login to mysql database. I am using windows 10 wamp64 installation.

I get the following error on the console:
C:\wamp64\bin\mysql\mysql5.7.9\bin> mysql
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'ODBC'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

All this started after playing with a Stripe integration. Any ideas?

Comment: Not sure where the 'ODBC' came from. Reference to Wu Tang Clan?

Comment: try specifying a username that you know, Look at [this answer ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29112800/4797158)